# Github API v3 giving 404 errors

Tags: github, github-api

Im using Joomla platform JGithub to communicate with Github API v3.
The code are all ok and i was able to use all GET methods (getComment etc).
But all POST, DELETE methods are failing with 404 error with a message Nothing Found.

Am just using username and password for authentication (No Oauth and stuff..)
Any idea why this error might be.
Another Joomla code was able to do this with the same script.
This is what confusing me.

Comment: Can you post sample code? You can try doing things using cURL from the command line and this is a good way to test whether you have things working correctly.

Comment: If something goes wrong, you'll get a 404 regardless. This to prevent scrapping for private repo's .

https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication